# Number theory proof $(a\cdot d) \bmod (c\cdot d) = (a \bmod c) \cdot d$ and $(a \cdot d) \operatorname{div} (c \cdot d) = a \operatorname{div} c$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given are $c,d \in \mathbb{N^+}$. Prove that for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}:$

$(a\cdot d) \bmod (c\cdot d) = (a \bmod c) \cdot d$ and $(a \cdot d) \operatorname{div} (c \cdot d) = a \operatorname{div} c$

I tried solving it by rewriting using definition $a = (a \operatorname{div} d)\cdot d + a \bmod d \: \land \: 0 \leq a \bmod d < d$, but this just adds a lot of large terms, even including an $(a\cdot d)^2$, which doesn't seem useful. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Hint** $\ a = qc + r\iff  ad = qcd + rd.\ $ Verify the needed inequalities.

Comment: @BillDubuque It can be so easy sometimes. The tip gave the requested $(a$ mod $c) \cdot d$ almost right away. I however can't get from $(a$ div $c)\cdot c \cdot d$ to $a$ div $d$. For this I need the inequalities? This only yields $a - d < (a$ div $c)c \leq a$

Comment: Use that $(0\le r < c)\,$ times $d$ yields $\,0\le rd < cd\,$, and use the fact that the quotient and remainder are unique.